# alpine js class binding with multiple condition

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I need to bind classes with multiple condition.

```php
:class="showMenu === true ? 'bg-chevron' : 'bg-chevron-blue bg-contain', showDetail === true ? 'rotate-180' : ''"
```

I use different colored icons according to showMenu and they should rotate according to showDetail. I seperate them with comma but only first condition works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple class bindings you need to use ternary conditions with in `[]`

```
:class="[showMenu === true ? 'bg-chevron' : 'bg-chevron-blue bg-contain', showDetail === true ? 'rotate-180' : '']"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.js"></script>
<div x-data="{showMenu:true, showDetail: true}">
  <label for="name" :class="[(showMenu === true ? 'bg-chevron' : 'bg-chevron-blue bg-contain'),(showDetail === true ? 'rotate-180' : '')]"  >Name:</label>
  <input id="name" type="text" x-model="name" />
  <p x-text="name">
</div>
```

Comment: Is "=== true" needed?

Comment: :class="[showMenu ? 'bg-chevron' : 'bg-chevron-blue bg-contain', showDetail ? 'rotate-180' : '']"

Comment: As per your required condition, above question needed multiple ternary conditions to add classes for either condition.